# How to build a LM393 MQ-2 smoke sensor circuit with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: sensor

I have a LM393 MQ-2 smoke sensor, and I want to build a circuit with a Raspberry Pi.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: yeap, but finding nothing

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=LM393+MQ-2+raspberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry Pi doesn't have any analog Pin so you will need an external ADC. 
so there are two option

1. get an external ADC with inbuilt amplifier. I will say look into [ADS1115](https://www.controleverything.com/content/Analog-Digital-Converters?sku=ADS1115_I2CADC).
2. the other option is go with a MQ2 sensor which comes with an on board Analog chip. So this will be the best way to go. 
   you can look into this [MQ2 gas sensor](https://www.controleverything.com/content/Gas?sku=ADC121C_I2CGAS_MQ2)
   this one comes with I2C, so its easy to use and no need to use an external amp.